# <Nav> is not re-rendering on location change even though wrapped in <Route>

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom`. I have a child within a `<Route>` that is not re-rendering even though the location is changed due to click on `<NavLink>` in the `<Nav>`. The `<Header>` is responsible for rendering the `<Route>` which renders the `<Nav>`:

The `<Header>` renders this:

```
class Header extends PureComponent<void, void, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <h2>Catchem</h2>
                <Route component={Nav} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

We see that line `<Route component={Nav} />`, I am expecting this to re-render every time the path changes. However it is not. Can you please help me understand why it is not re-rendering when path changes? Clicking the `<NavLink>`s in the `<Nav>` is causing a path change.

Here is my `<Nav>`:

```
class Nav extends PureComponent<void, Props, void> {
    render() {
        const { location } = this.props;
        console.log('nav props:', this.props);
        return (
            <div className="nav">
                { PAGES.map( ({path, label}) => (
                    <NavLink exact className="topnav-link" activeClassName="topnav-link-selected" key={path} to={path} location={location} exact>
                        {label}
                    </NavLink>
                )) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my `<App>`:

```
const PAGES = [
    { path:'/',           label:'Asset Manager',     Body:AssetManager    },
    { path:'/tags',       label:'Tag Manager',       Body:TagManager      },
    { path:'/tag-groups', label:'Tag Group Manager', Body:TagGroupManager },
]

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Header />
                        <p className="App-intro">
                            Gotta <code>catch'em</code> all!!
                        </p>
                        <Switch>
                            { PAGES.map( ({ Body, path }) => <Route path={path} key={path} exact component={Body} /> ) }
                            <Route component={Body404} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some tests and it looks my answer is wrong (so I will delete it probably) ... Are you exporting your `Header` wrapped by `withRouter()` ?

Comment: Ah I am not using `withRouter` on `Header`. I thought wrapping anything in `<Route>` would make it like a redux `connect`'ed component, where just that component is subscriped to redux store. Route does not work like this?

Comment: @Melounek wrapping `Header` with `withRouter` and also `Nav` in a `withRouter` does the trick, but is there a way to wrap just `Nav` with `withRouter`? I don't get why `Header` also needs to be wrapped. Is this because `Header` is the first child of `BrowserRouter` and everything on the way down needs a `withRouter` wrap?

Comment: like [documentation] said: _"withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders."_  - So I think it's necessary for passing history object to the `<Route>`

Comment: I think I understand now finally. Thank you all!